# Why are Google and Bing images are misaligned in QGIS3 even with OTF on?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

While I always used both Google and Bing images in QGIS3 only recently have I noticed they are misaligned even with On The Fly reprojection on. In the example below the polygon shows this misfit. Which one is wrong and how can both be reprojected to be correctly aligned? I tested with a geodetic control point in the ground (bottom images) and verified that the google image is correct (left). The Bing image is off by 6 meters. Both added from QuickMapServices plugin.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Even a very accurate measuring instrument has a measurement error. Space imagery is no exception.

Answer (score 2):

They are not, the difference is due to the diffrent imaging angles, and the fact that the terrain itself is matched. Anything above the surface, like buildings, may be shifted due to the perspectives.

Try marking out the building's footprint, not the roof, and you will see they match. Yhough there still may be some sideway shift, there's seldom absolute accuracy. Sub meter is considered very good for satellite imagery.

Comment: thanks, but that's not the case actually. I've added an image with a point at the ground which is actually a geodetic control point. I tested this point and the google image (left image) is the correct one. Bing is off by 6 meters. So what is the issue here? Why is the Bing image off by so much?

Comment: QC issues. Errors can and are introduced from the satellite imagery source, image registration, DSM quality and resolution, image mosaicing, and perhaps even the reprojection and tiling to generate the basemap by Bing. If you have GCPs and can independently verify the accuracy, that's the best approach.